# Method performance comparison

Tags: java, opencv, matrix

Which method is **faster** for **retrieving a submat**, `adjustROI()` or `submat()` ? I want to know it because im **working with java** and i got a loop over many images of size 1600*1200.

Thanks in advance.

*P.S.: For anyone, who has noticed that the same post exists in the OpenCV Q&A Forum: Since nobody was able to answer the question, I decided to put it on Stackoverflow to increase the chance of someone answering it.*

Comment: Why don't you make the benchmark?

Comment: I thought someone would know because he has already tested it. If not, i am going to post my benchmark as soon as possbile.

Comment: I cannot understand why people downvote. This question demands something called "sharing of knowledge".

Comment: You can use System.nonaTime() before and after each method call to caculate time consumed by them.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is benchmarking as suggested by @Ilya Kurnosov.
However I predict virtually **no difference** based on the source below.
It would seem that Mat creation and JNI call overhead would be big compared to the work that actually occurs, but a benchmark may prove me wrong.

A big issue with both methods, if you are sliding a rectangle around pixel by pixel, is that you will create almost two million objects. (OTOH you can do this in c++ without creating any new objects, so if its gotta be fast ...)

```
public Mat submat(int rowStart, int rowEnd, int colStart, int colEnd)
{

    Mat retVal = new Mat(n_submat_rr(nativeObj, rowStart, rowEnd, colStart, colEnd));

    return retVal;
}

public Mat adjustROI(int dtop, int dbottom, int dleft, int dright)
{

    Mat retVal = new Mat(n_adjustROI(nativeObj, dtop, dbottom, dleft, dright));

    return retVal;
}
```